# Buscar os dados dos últimos 7 dias a partir da data actual

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estou a fazer a fazer uma consulta à BD, e quero receber resultados dos últimos 7 dias a partir da data actual. Para isso, tenho um campo `data` do tipo DATA (yyyy-mm-dd) na tabela. Estou a fazer a consulta em php, por sua vez mysql.

```
$query = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM tbl_registos WHERE data >= '$last_7_days');
```

A variável `$last_7_days` deverá ser o valor dos últimos 7 dias, tendo sempre em atenção os meses e os anos. Existe alguma maneira mais fácil de fazer isto?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Se você deseja buscar a partir da data atual, você não precisar informar nenhuma variável de data. MySQL é inteligente :), e é capaz de fazer a conta de quando é sete dias no passado.

### Faça assim:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabela 
WHERE 
  data BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()-7 AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

`BETWEEN` retorna o que há entre essas datas.

`CURRENT_DATE()` retorna a data atual.

`CURRENT_DATE()-7` retorna a data atual, menos sete dias.

Referências:

- [MySQL Comparison Functions and Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html)
- [MySQL Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! ;)

Answer (score 8):

Adicionar essa cláusula `WHERE` vai pegar a data atual e subtrair 7 dias, lembrando que seu campo data, tem q ser do tipo `date` msm

```
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_registos WHERE data BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()");
```

Comment: neste caso vai-me devolver todos os valores, em vez dos ultimos 7 dias

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Tabelas WHERE Campos BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY";
```