# Buscar os dados dos últimos 7 dias a partir da data actual (2014-12-11 11:06:09)

Tags: mysql, sql

Após visualizar a [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9296/1333), surgiu a seguinte dúvida que é, no caso que o campo date está no seguinte formato 2014-12-11 11:06:09, como fazer pra retornar apenas os últimos 7 dias?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testei aqui e funcionou:

```
SELECT * FROM sua_tabela WHERE seu_campo
BETWEEN TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 day)) AND NOW();
```

> Acredito que tenha um jeito mais fácil de fazer.

Answer (score -2):

Faça assim:

```
SELECT * FROM sua_tabela WHERE seu_campo
BETWEEN date(date(now()) - 7) and date(now());
```