# sistema de contagem de dias em php

Tags: php, mysql

bom dia como eu posso fazer um sistema que cadastre a data atual no banco e depois eu quero que ele mostre como novo tipo assim eu quero que enquanto a data que foi cadastrada for menor que 15 dias ele mostre como novo e depois ele saia como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

No seu SQL para selecionar a data:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE 
data BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()-15 AND CURRENT_DATE();
```

Se o retorno for positivo (true), a data é menor do que 15 dias, então, não é mais novo... se for negativo (false), é novo.

Questão de referência: [Buscar os dados dos últimos 7 dias a partir da data actual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9296/buscar-os-dados-dos-%C3%BAltimos-7-dias-a-partir-da-data-actual)

Comment: vou implementar aqui irei testar se ocorrer algum erro postarei aqui estou terminando outra parte do projeto obrigado pela resposta

Answer (score 0):

Como eu imagino que você deseja trazer o objeto independente dele ser novo ou não, sugiro a seguinte lógica:

```
// $objeto é o objeto que você trouxe do banco, e possui a data como um atributo
$novo = false;
if ($objeto->getData()->diff(new \DateTime())->days <= 15) {
    $novo = true;
}
```

Daí basta fazer o que você quiser com base no conteúdo de `$novo`: se você irá exibir uma imagem, um botão etc.