# Faturas não pagas a mais de 10 dias

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho uma tabela de faturas e clientes.

Na tabela de faturas, por exemplo, eu tenho os campos cliente_id, status e data

Na tabela de clientes id, nome, etc...

O que preciso é listar todas as faturas, que o status ainda esta em Aberto (no caso NP - de não pago). Mas desejo apenas listar as faturas que não foram pagas a mais de 10 dias.

Exemplo da listagem

```
Cliente     Data de Vencimento   Valor
Teste       10/08/2016           R$ 100,00
Teste       09/08/2016           R$ 200,00
Teste       05/08/2016           R$ 100,00
Teste       01/08/2016           R$ 100,00
Teste       10/07/2016           R$ 100,00
```

Utilizo PHP e MySQL.

Comment: [Buscar os dados dos últimos 7 dias a partir da data actual](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9296/70)

Answer (score 0):

Algo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM faturas WHERE status = 'NP' AND vencimento BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()-10 AND CURRENT_DATE();
```

Como você não postou a estrutura das tabelas, não deu pra dar uma query mais adequada a sua situação.

Mesmo assim, espero que ajude!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `DATEDIFF()` para verificar quantos dias passou de uma determinada data fazendo `INNER JOIN` com a tabela clientes.

```
SELECT 
    clientes.nome, faturas.data, faturas.valor
FROM
    faturas
        INNER JOIN
    clientes ON (faturas.cliente_id = clientes.id)
WHERE
    faturas.status = 'NP'
        AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), faturas.data) >= 10
```