# Como seria a query para retornar valores em um intervalo determinado?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela com os seguintes *rows*:

- code (int)
- vacina (varchar)
- dt_vencimento (datetime)

Preciso de uma *query* para retornar todas as vacinas que vão vencer no intervalo de 10 dias, contando a data de hoje.

Tentei algo deste tipo que vi [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1713381/2570426)<sup>SOen</sup> usando `INTERVAL`:

```
SELECT * FROM tblVacinas WHERE dt_vencimento >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY);
```

**Obs.:** não funcionou.

Como seria a *query* para retornar valores em intervalo determinado contando a partir da data atual?

Comment: [Buscar os dados dos últimos 7 dias a partir da data actual](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9296/91) Detalhe você precisa compar as unidades corretas, use `date_format()` em dt_vencimento para especificar o formato correto (eliminar hora, minuto e segundos) para pesquisar. `date` = ano, mês e dia; `datetime` = ano, mês, dia, hora, minuto e segundo.

Comment: Creio que você queria dizer columns e não rows.

Answer (score 1):

O problema da sua query é que nessa parte `>= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)` você diz para busca datas que sejam **maior ou igual** a data de hoje mais 10 dias, exemplo: no dia 23/01/2017 sua query só vai buscar datas além do dia 02/02/2017.

Se você quer buscar um intervalo, basta usar o `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblVacinas
WHERE dt_vencimento BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tblVacinas WHERE dt_vencimento >= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 10 DAY);
```

Tente utilizar o Comando DATE_SUB();

Referência : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub

Espero que ajude.