# Como buscar registros salvos na semana atual?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou a fazer uma consulta uma base de dados, e pretendo listar os registros da semana atual. Seria algo baseado na pergunta sobre [buscar os dados dos últimos 7 dias a partir da data actual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9298/35406), porém em vez de ser a partir da data corrente, seria do início da semana.

Veja abaixo as colunas da tabela `tbl_vacina`:

```
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
|     ID     |    vacina    |    data_criacao   |
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
|     1      |    Cinomose  |2017-06-10 10:11:15|
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
|     2      | Coronavirose |2017-06-09 10:11:15|
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

- `id` - *int*
- `vacina` - *varchar(512)*
- `data_criacao` - *timestamp*

Como seria uma *query* para retornar todos os registros salvos na semana atual?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Eu sugeria o usa da função [YEARWEEK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek)

```
SELECT *
FROM   tblVacina
WHERE  YEARWEEK(data_criacao, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)
```

(Estou a tentar criar o SQLFiddle mas não estou a conseguir executar)

Comment: Confirmado, funciona. kkk eu devia ter insistido mais nessa solução, é mais elegante mesmo. Ja tinha votado +1 nela.

Comment: Obrigado, de qualquer das formas ficam aqui duas versões (+1):)

Comment: Eu acho essa a mais adequada para ser marcada como aceita

Comment: Funcionou beleza! Obrigado!

Answer (score 9):

Se fosse comparar se duas datas arbitrárias são na mesma semana:

```
SELECT
   campos
FROM
   tabela
WHERE
   DATE_SUB(data1, INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(data1)-1 DAY)
   =
   DATE_SUB(data2, INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(data2)-1 DAY);
```

Aplicando ao seu caso:

```
WHERE
   DATE_SUB(data_criacao, INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(data_criacao)-1 DAY)
   =
   DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)-1 DAY);
```

Basicamente, se pegamos uma data e extraimos o dia da semana atual, temos o domingo imediatamente anterior. Se for igual nos dois casos, é a mesma semana.

Se não tiver dados futuros no DB, pode simplificar assim:

```
SELECT
   campos
FROM
   tabela
WHERE
   data_criacao >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)-1 DAY)
```

Como estamos usando a data de hoje como referência, basta que a `data_criacao` seja igual ou mais nova do que o último domingo.

Comment: Bacco, " se pegamos uma data e extraimos o dia da semana atual, temos o domingo imediatamente anterior" não percebi bem, podes-me explicar sff

Comment: @Miguel se hoje é terça, e eu tiro 3 da data de hoje, cai no mesmo dia do que pegar a data de quinta e tirar 5. o DAYOFWEEK devolve numericamente o dia da semana.

Comment: Mas estás sempre a subtrair sempre um, ou seja, se hoje é terça vai ser segunda, certo?

Comment: está subtraindo DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)-1 - Esse DAYOFWEEK retorna o dia da semana de 1 a 7; o -1 é só pra transformar de 0 a 6.

Comment: Ha ok percebi, obagdo Bacco

Comment: Bacco obrigado! Funcionou beleza mas realmente a resposta do Bruno funciona também e está mais simples.