# Como resgatar todos os dados do mês atual agrupados por data?

Tags: mysql

Tenho a seguinte table:

```
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
|     ID     |    vacina    |       data        |
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
|     1      |    Cinomose  |2017-07-10 10:11:15|
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
|     2      | Coronavirose |2017-08-09 10:11:15|
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
|     3      |   Vermifugo  |2017-10-10 10:11:15|
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
|     4      | Anti-pulgas  |2017-07-25 10:11:15|
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
|     5      | Anti-rábica  |2017-06-06 10:11:15|
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
|     6      |      V4      |2017-07-10 10:11:15|
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

Gostaria de uma query que me retorne a quantidade de vacinas que possui no dia em relação ao mês atual, considerando que hoje é `2017-07-25`. Por exemplo:

```
+------------+-------------------+
|    qnd     |       data        |
+------------+-------------------+
|     2      |2017-07-10 10:11:15|
+------------+-------------------+
|     1      |2017-07-25 10:11:15|
+------------+-------------------+
```

Minha iniciativa inicial foi desta forma abaixo:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as qnd, datetime_start as date FROM `tbl_delivery` GROUP BY datetime_start
```

Porém assim faz o processo de contar e agrupar mas retorna dados de todos os mês que estão contidos na tabela.

Tente usar essa pergunta de: [como buscar registros salvos na semana atual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/179865/como-buscar-registros-salvos-na-semana-atual), mas o agrupamento não funfou.

Qual seria a forma mais viável de resgatar todos os dados do mês atual agrupados por data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A ideia seria a mesma da semana atual, basta utilizar a função `MONTH` do MySQL para verificar o mês e comparar com a data atual, `CURRENT_DATE`.

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) as `qtd`,
         `datetime_start` as `date`
    FROM `tbl_delivery`
   WHERE MONTH(`datetime_start`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
GROUP BY `datetime_start`
```

Comment: Apesar da outra respostar ser também valida mostrando a comparação em relação ao tempo, vou validar esta por não ter que indicar o intervalo de datas para comparação, no qual o DNick usar `BETWEEN`. Vlw.

Answer (score 3):

A resposta do Anderson está correta, mas uma ressalva a se fazer é o processamento dos dados. Em uma tabela com muitos registros a consulta será mais lenta devido a comparação

```
WHERE MONTH(`datetime_start`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
```

Pois será comparados todos os registros do banco em busca do mês atual `MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())`, tornando a busca mais granular.

Se for possível, procure passar o intervalo das datas que precisa com o parâmetro `BEETWEEN`.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(primary_key) as qtd, DAY(datetime_start)
FROM
    tbl_delivery
WHERE
    datetime_start BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-06-30'
    group by DAY(datetime_start)
```

Segue comparação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Voce deve utilizar uma clausula Where em seu codigo antes do group by:

```
WHERE datetime_start BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

caso voce queira apenas da semana atual pode usar desta forma:

```
WHERE datetime_start BETWEEN (sysdate-7) AND sysdate;
```

já no caso do mes pode torcar o -7 por -30

Comment: Assim, se funcionar, não pegaria os registros dos últimos 30 dias?